# Private arguments not saving things in C++ program

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Figuras.h"
using namespace std;
void error(){
        cout<<"algo ha ido mal vuelve a empezar"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }

int main(){
    Figuras fig;
    vec V;
    string tip;
    cout << "Triangle = Tr / Cuadrat = Cu / Rectangle = Re / Segment = Se / Cercle = Ce" << endl;
    cin >> tip;

    if(tip=="Tr"){
        V = vector<pair<double,double>>(3);
    }
    else if(tip == "Cu" or tip == "Re"){
        V = vector<pair<double,double>>(4);
    }
    else if (tip == "Se" or tip == "Ce"){
        V = vector<pair<double,double>>(2);
    }
    else error();

    for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++) { //fill vector with coords
        cout << "Introdueix coordenada numero: " << i<<" format (double,double): " <<endl;
        cout << "x: ";
        cin >> V[i].first;
        cout << "y: ";
        cin >> V[i].second;

    }


    fig.crea_figura(tip,V);
    fig.mostrar_fig();


    }
```

Figuras.cpp

```
#include "Figuras.h"

using namespace std;


    /*void Figuras::Figura(){
        tipo = NULL;
        Coord = NULL;
    }*/

    string Figuras::get_tipo (){
        return tipo;
    };

    vec Figuras::get_coords (){
        return Coord;

    };

    punto Figuras::get_inicio (){
        return inicio;
    };

    void Figuras::Set_tipo (string typ){
        tipo = typ;
    };

    void Figuras::Set_Coord (vec V){
        punto p;
        int x= V.size();
        Coord=vector<pair<double,double>>(x);
        for ( int i =0; i<x; i++){
            Coord[i].first = p.first;
            Coord[i].second = p.second;

        }
    };

    void Figuras::Set_inicio (punto ini){
        inicio = ini;
    }; 
    void Figuras::crea_figura (string tip, vec V){
        Set_tipo(tip);
        Set_Coord(V);

    };

    void Figuras::trasladar (punto P){
        double difx,dify;
        difx=P.first - inicio.first;
        dify=P.second - inicio.second;
        vec V;
        Figuras::get_coords();
        if (!Coord.empty()){
            for(int i=0; i<Coord.size(); i++){
                Coord[i].first += difx;
                Coord[i].second += dify;
            }
        }
        else cout<< "no hay coords"<<endl;
    };

    void Figuras::mostrar_fig (){
        vec V;
        V=get_coords();
        punto ini;
        ini=get_inicio();
        string tip;
        tip=get_tipo();
        cout<<"tipo: "<<tip<<endl;
        for (int i =0; i<V.size(); i++){
            cout<<"punto "<< i+1<<": "<<"("<<V[i].first<<","<<V[i].second<<")"<<endl;
        }
        cout<< "punto inicial: ("<<ini.first<<","<<ini.second<<")"<<endl;

    };
```

Figuras.h

```
#ifndef FIGURAS_H
#define FIGURAS_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


typedef vector < pair < double, double >>vec;

typedef pair < double, double >punto;



class Figuras
{


private:
string tipo;

vec Coord;

punto inicio={0.0,0.0};


public:
string get_tipo ();

vec get_coords ();

punto get_inicio ();

void Set_tipo (string typ);

void Set_Coord (vec V);

void Set_inicio (punto ini);

void crea_figura (string tip, vec vec);

void trasladar (punto P);

void mostrar_fig ();

};


#endif
```

Let me explain the problem when I do, `crea_figura(tip,V);` and then mostrar_fig() at main.cpp line 39,40.

This happens:

```
Triangle = Tr / Cuadrat = Cu / Rectangle = Re / Segment = Se / Cercle = Ce
Tr
Introdueix coordenada numero: 0 format (double,double): 
x: 1.1
y: 1.1
Introdueix coordenada numero: 1 format (double,double): 
x: 2.2
y: 2.2
Introdueix coordenada numero: 2 format (double,double): 
x: 3.1
y: 1.1
tipo: Tr
punto 1: (0,0)
punto 2: (0,0)
punto 3: (0,0)
punto inicial: (0,0)
```

All points appear to be empty and I can not realize why is that for. Is there any other way to initialize the class (another type of constructor)?

Comment: In `Set_Coord`, you assign to each element of the vector the same value of `p`. You don't use anything from `V` there expect for it's size.

Comment: p is only default initialized in Set_Coord

Comment: BTW. Don't reimplement the wheel. `void Figuras::Set_Coord (vec V){ Coord = V; }` will do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Some more comments: your naming convention is inconsistent; you always pass by value, which is very suboptimal in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code

```
void Figuras::Set_Coord (vec V){
    punto p;
    int x= V.size();
    Coord=vector<pair<double,double>>(x);
    for ( int i =0; i<x; i++){
        Coord[i].first = p.first;
        Coord[i].second = p.second;

    }
};
```

`p` is an empty point, that's why all your points are empty.

You're doing things the difficult way, really it should be easy. Try this

```
void Figuras::Set_Coord (vec V){
    Coord = V;
}
```

That's all you need to do.

The above code is correct, but for a more efficient way you should *pass by reference*.

```
void Figuras::Set_Coord (const vec& V){
    Coord = v;
}
```